# Более малочисленный - что это значит?

Tags: идиоматика

более малочисленный - что это значит?

Правильно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы от такого выражения уклонился. Видимо, пытались сказать "(сравн.) меньший по численности".

Comment: Поддержу, уклонился бы тоже. Ключевое слово - выражение. "Более малочисленный" - очевидное  противоречие, заложенное в двух словах. 

Вот пример противоречия внутри слова, что ещё круче. Плановое производство, личные планы рабочих, которые перевыполняются постоянно... и у всех появляются планы перевыполнять планы. В случае конфуза, т. е. неперевыполнения плана , в умах плановиков рождается термин "недоперевыполнение", означающий, что план перевыполнен, но обязательство нарушено и премии ждать не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Я смотрю, вопросы на эту тему идут косяком.

Лично я не вижу в данном случае никакого "криминала". Существует **качественный** признак "*малочисленные*". Для сравнения по этому признаку используются **относительные** признаки ("более", "менее", "столь-же", "не более", "не менее" и т.д.).

"Неприятность" заключается в формальном противопоставлении ("более мало").. Но для носителя языка подобная конструкция проблемы не представляет. Куда хуже может оказаться конструкция "менее малочисленные".

Comment: НАДО меньший по численности, больший по численности, на крайний случай корявое -  малочисленнее. А то получается более можно, а менее нельзя, непорядок.

Comment: "Но для носителя языка подобная конструкция проблемы не представляет." greydog

Есть опросный лист и процент высказываний носителей языка?

Comment: "более мало" greydog. Это совсем не одно и то же.

Ваш пример можно как-то представить в ситуации: более мало, чем велико, и таким образом оправдать. "Более малочисленный" - скверный тупиковый случай.

Comment: @petro Никто и не говорил, что мир стоит на принципах порядка и равновесия. Впрочем, Вы можете утешиться тем, что в русском языке есть другая "неравновесная пара", компенсирующая "непорядок", на который Вы указали.

@shampar Попробуйте "отредактировать" фразу без потери смыслового и эмоционального посыла: *"СПС - партия ещё более малочисленная, чем Партия Любителей Пива"*

Comment: Смешно.Более  менее больно и довольно мало. Прямо информативно - экспрессивно, и носителю языка со мной очень повезло.

Comment: ..Гмм... Пожалуй, побуду занудой.

Конструкция "более-менее" (**через дефис**) является "разговорным" аналогом конструкции "более **или** менее". И "относительной характеристикой" не является. А потому - со словом "больно" использоваться не может.

Конструкция "довольно мало" - вполне "законная" конструкция, характеризующая "заметную, но не критичную недостаточность" чего либо.

Comment: greydog: "СПС - партия ещё более малочисленная, чем Партия Любителей Пива"

"СПС - партия с ещё меньшим членством, чем Партия Любителей Пива"

Comment: greydog: Конструкция "довольно мало" - вполне "законная" конструкция, характеризующая "заметную, но не критичную недостаточность".

Зачем создавать конструкцию, если "довольно мало" = "недостаточно"?

Comment: @shampar.

1. Боюсь, "меньшее членство" - конструкция куда менее понятная, чем "более малочисленная". В чём у этой партии членство? В какой-то "надпартийной" организации? Про "эмоциональный посыл" я даже не говорю.

2. Насколько "недостаточно"? Я, помнится, дал 2 границы.

Answer (score 0):

БОЛЕЕ МАЛОЧИСЛЕННЫЙ - ЧТО ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ?

Это значит, что выделяется группа предметов/явлений, которую называют малочисленной (с небольшим/малым  количеством),  при этом обозначается какая-то граница. 
УЖЕ ВНУТРИ ЭТОЙ ГРУППЫ ВЫДЕЛЯЮТСЯ ПОДГРУППЫ, КОТОРЫЕ СРАВНИВАЮТСЯ ПО ЧИСЛЕННОСТИ: эта группа более малочисленная, чем та  (менее малочисленных нет, иначе выйдем за границу группы).Получаем: этот народ более малочисленный, чем тот.

Аналогично с точки зрения семантики строится выражение «более мелкий», например: более мелкий масштаб среди мелких масштабов.  Мелкий  - это тоже маленький, но лексической несочетаемости  «более маленький» нет, и выражение воспринимается как норма.

ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ ТАК ГОВОРИТЬ?

По лексической сочетаемости выражение «более малочисленный» хуже, чем «более мелкий», но лучше, чем «более маленький».  С точки зрения семантики, это выражение является НЕОБХОДИМЫМ, ХОТЯ И НЕ ОЧЕНЬ КРАСИВЫМ, так как близкий синоним «меньший по численности» неточен по значению (в этом случае малочисленность  группы не обозначена).

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1) ...если б в Абхазии жил какой-нибудь народ, более малочисленный, чем абхазцы... (Фазиль Искандер).

(2)Самки, во всех случаях более малочисленные, уже потому не могут совершать подбора, что они всегда снабжены менее развитыми глазами, чем самцы (И. И. Мечников).